# Converting HTML form input to PDF - How to print more than 2 outputs

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, pdf

I'm new to coding and trying to accomplish passing input data from a form to a PHP response page and displaying it in the browser. The user can then click on a button to save the HTML element to PDF. The code works when displaying 2 form outputs eg.  but as soon as I add more outputs from the form the javascript doesn't seem to run. I cant understand what is going wrong.

HTML form input page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src ="ff.png">
<form action="response.php" method="post">
Invoice Number/Reference:<br>
<input type="text" name="ref"><br>
Customer Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="cname"><br>
<br>
Item:<br>
<input type="text" name="i1">
Cost
<input type="text" name="c1">
<br>
Item:<br>
<input type="text" name="i2">
Cost
<input type="text" name="c2">
<br>
Item:<br>
<input type="text" name="i3">
Cost
<input type="text" name="c3">
<br><br>
Total Cost:<br>
<input type="text" name="t1"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP response page with button to download to PDF

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js" ></script>
<script>
function generatePDF() {
 var doc = new jsPDF();  //create jsPDF object
  doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById("input_data"), // page element which you want to print as PDF
  15,
  15, 
  {
    'width': 170  //set width
  },
  function(a) 
   {
    doc.save("ClientInvoice.pdf"); // save file name as HTML2PDF.pdf
  });
}
</script>
</head>


  <body>
    <div id="input_data">
      <img src = "ff.png" width="150"><br>
      <h2>Invoice Reference: <?php echo $_POST["ref"]; ?></h2><br>
      Customer name: <?php echo $_POST["cname"]; ?><br><br>
      Item: <?php echo $_POST["i1"]; ?><br>
      £ <?php echo $_POST["c1"]; ?><br>
      Item: <?php echo $_POST["i2"]; ?><br>
      £ <?php echo $_POST["c2"]; ?><br>
      Item: <?php echo $_POST["i3"]; ?><br>
      £ <?php echo $_POST["c3"]; ?><br><br>
      Total: <?php echo $_POST["t1"]; ?><br><br>

      Thank you for choosing My Company.
  
    </div>
    
<a href="javascript:generatePDF()">Dowload PDF</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case applying **jspdf.debug.js**

1. Please enclose your string data by `<div>` (so use `</div>TEXT</div>`)
2. Please use `&#163;` for the pound sign (to avoid seeing weird characters when you view this character on page)

So please change your code (response.php) to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js" ></script>
<script>
function generatePDF() {
 var doc = new jsPDF();  //create jsPDF object
  doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById("input_data"), // page element which you want to print as PDF
  15,
  15, 
  {
    'width': 170  //set width
  },
  function(a) 
   {
    doc.save("ClientInvoice.pdf"); // save file name as HTML2PDF.pdf
  });
}
</script>
</head>


  
  <body>
    <div id="input_data">
      <img src = "ff.png" width="150"><br>
      <h2>Invoice Reference: <?php echo $_POST["ref"]; ?></h2><br>
      <div>Customer name: <?php echo $_POST["cname"]; ?></div><br><br>
      <div>Item: <?php echo $_POST["i1"]; ?></div><br>  
      <div>&#163; <?php echo $_POST["c1"]; ?></div><br>
      <div>Item: <?php echo $_POST["i2"]; ?></div><br>
      <div>&#163; <?php echo $_POST["c2"]; ?></div><br>
      <div>Item: <?php echo $_POST["i3"]; ?></div><br>
      <div>&#163; <?php echo $_POST["c3"]; ?></div><br><br>
      <div>Total: <?php echo $_POST["t1"]; ?></div><br><br>
      <div>Thank you for choosing My Company.</div>
     </div>
    
<a href="javascript:generatePDF()">Dowload PDF</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

See a **working version** here:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO17apr2022.html

Answer (score 0):

Here, if we add styles in the HTML file, we do not get the added styles from it when downloading the file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here, if we add styles to the HTML file, those added styles are not included when downloading the file.